# Does the curve $(t^2,t^2)$ has singularity at $t=0$?

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, parametrization, singularity

Suppose the curve $\gamma(t)=(t^2,t^2),t\in (-\infty,+\infty)$,then its speed is $\dot \gamma(t)=(2t,2t)$.The speed vanishes at $t=0$.So,the curve is not regular i.e.the curve is singular at $t=0$.I want to know what is causing this singularity?Is this singularity removable?

Comment: Presumably you confuse "singular" with "not immersive".

Comment: Notice that you end up with a ray .... with a boundary point at the origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept of removable singularity arises in the context of complex analysis. We say that an isolated singularity $z_0$ of an analytic function $f$ is a removable singularity when we can extend $f$ to an analytic function whose domain is $D_f\cup\{z_0\}$.

But here, no such concept exists. We just say that $0$ is a singular point of $\gamma$.

Comment: What are the types of singularities?

Comment: In the context of analytic functions, there are threee types of isolated singularities: removable singularities, poles, and essential singularities.

Comment: What about branching points like  $\sqrt x$ at 0?